# Seaborn align plots in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm using Seaborn to plot 3 ghaphs. I would like to know how could I align vertically different plots.

This is my plot so far:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

flatui = ["#636EFA", "#EF553B", "#00CC96", "#AB63FA"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 7))    
plot=sns.lineplot(ax=ax,x="number of weeks", y="avg streams", hue="year", data=df, palette=flatui)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:,.2f}'.format(x/1000) + 'K'))

plot.set(title='Streams trend')
plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2))

    

    
fig, ax =plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(17,7))
plot = sns.barplot(x="Artist", y="Releases", data = result.head(10), ax=ax[0])
plot.set_xticklabels(
    plot.get_xticklabels(), 
    rotation=90, 
    horizontalalignment='center',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='x-large'

)
plot=sns.barplot(x="Artist", y="Streams", data = result.head(10), ax=ax[1])
plot.set_xticklabels(
    plot.get_xticklabels(), 
    rotation=90, 
    horizontalalignment='center',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='x-large'

)
```

Basically I create a figure where I plot the trend graph and then a figure with 2 subplots where I plot my 2 bar plots.

What I would like to do is to align the trend plot and the 2 barplots. As you might notice on the left, the trend plot and the first barplot are not aligned, I would like to make the two figures start from the same point (like at the ending of the trend plot and the second barplot, where the 2 graphs are aligned).

How could I do that?

Comment: Can you confirm that you want 2 separate figures, and not 1 figure with 3 subplots?

Comment: @DizietAsahi It's the same. I created 2 figures because I couldn't find a way to make a single plot occupy 2 "slots" in a subplot. The goal is to have the trend plot above and the 2 barplot below as showed in my image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [GridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html)

```
fig = plt.figure()
gs0 = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(2,2, figure=fig)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0,:])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1,0])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1,1])

sns.lineplot(ax=ax1, ...)
sns.barplot(ax=ax2, ...)
sns.barplot(ax=ax3, ...)
```

If you have the newest version of matplotlib, you can also use [the new semantic figure composition engine](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/provisional/mosaic.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-provisional-mosaic-py)

```
axd = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True).subplot_mosaic(
    """
    AA
    BC
    """
)

sns.lineplot(ax=axd['A'], ...)
sns.barplot(ax=axd['B'], ...)
sns.barplot(ax=axd['C'], ...)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Is there a way to set a margin between the upper graph (the trend one) and the barplots? They're quite close to each other, I would like to move them a little lower

Comment: You can adjust the parameter `hspace` that you can pass to `GridSpec`, or to `subplot_mosaic()` via `gridspec_kw=`, see the links in my answer